# custom font selector only changes font once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface

I'm at a loss, I'm trying to allow users to select the font-family of some text output. The code basically boils down to this:

```
<div id='output'>
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
<select id='font-select'>
    <option value='Lucida Console'>Lucida Console</option>
    <option value='Courier New'>Courier New</option>
    <option value='Consolas'>Consolas</option>
</select>
```

With jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $('font-select').on( 'change',
        function()
        {
            $('output').css( 'font-family', $('#font-select').val() );
            console.log( 'Font changed' );
        });
});
```

I know the on-change event fires every time I select a different font, but the font in the div only changes the first time I choose one. After that I still get a 'font changed' notice in the console, but no actual change in the #output div.

I've tried changing it to

```
$(document).on( 'change', '#font-select',
    ....
```

I've also tried changing the id's to classes and selecting via class

```
$('.font-select').change(
    ....
```

With the same results. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is about the selectors you used. When you are trying to access element through id then you are suppose to add # in front.

Here is [fiddler][1] which works fine and solve your issue

Hope it helps.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/nfh5craz/
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned. I have the correct  selectors everywhere else, just not there.

Answer (score 1):

first i would always use the right selectors in jquery in your case use:

```
$('#font-select').on('change', function() {
    $('#output').css[....]
}
```

The '#' selects by id.

Second tip:

Try removing the font-family class first and then set a new one, sometimes jQuery/html gets confused when you set values to already existing properties (or at least i have the feeling it does :D )
So try something like this in your "change" function:

```
$('#output').css('font-family', ''); //this is basically standard but i dont like it...
$('#output').css( 'font-family', $('#font-select').val() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the id's correct in your jQuery (# missing).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('change', '#font-select', function() {
    $('#output').css('font-family', $('#font-select').val());
    console.log('Font changed');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='output'>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
</div>
<select id='font-select'>
    <option value='Lucida Console'>Lucida Console</option>
    <option value='Courier New'>Courier New</option>
    <option value='Consolas'>Consolas</option>
</select>
```